# NodeJS не завершает запись файла

Tags: filestream, node.js

Пытаюсь сделать загрузку изображений на сервер. Использую расширение "multer".
Вот пример кода сохранения файла:

```
var file = req.files.image,
    path = __dirname + '/uploads/';

var buffer = file.buffer, //Note: buffer only populates if you set inMemory: true.
    fileName = file.name;

var stream = fs.createWriteStream(path + fileName);

stream.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('Could not write file to memory.');
    res.status(400).send({
        message: 'Problem saving the file. Please try again.'
    });
});

stream.on('finish', function() {
    console.log('File saved successfully.');
    var data = {
        message: 'File saved successfully.'
    };
    res.jsonp(data);
});

stream.write(buffer);

stream.end();
console.log('Stream ended.');
```

Проблема в том, что не срабатывает событие "finish". Хотя файл сохраняется нормально, то есть он физически создается, содержимое записывается. Но вот не вызывается событие, что запись завершена.

У меня мало опыта работы с NodeJS, поэтому прошу помощи, как можно локализовать проблему и понять, что не так происходит?

А вообще есть необходимость в таком событии, как "finish"?
То есть после вызова `stream.write(buffer);` в начале будет записан файл, а потом программа продолжится со следующей инструкции?

Покопался, если правильно понял, то событие "finish" присутствует с версии 0.10 в NodeJS. Я же использую 0.8. Как мне в таком случае определить, что запись файла завершена и я могу отправлять ответ браузеру?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Что-то я не уверен, что

```
stream.on('finish', function() {
```

уместно в этой конструкции.

[Рекомендую рассмотреть вот этот пример на понимание.](https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/advanced/streams/how-to-use-fs-create-write-stream)

Comment: Событие "finish" я взял из примера в интернете. Немного недопонял пример по вашей ссылке, получается req.pipe(stream); говорит о том что когда завершится работа по записи файла то будет вызвано событие у req.on('end', function { ?

Но у меня событие "end" опять так и тоже не вызывается, получается я не могу узнать что запись завершена.

Comment: А вообще есть необходимость в таком событии как "finish"?
То есть после вызова `stream.write(buffer);` в начале будет записан файл, а потом программа продолжится со следующей инструкции?

Comment: Покопался, если правильно понял, то событие "finish" присутствует с версии 0.10 в NodeJS. Я же использую 0.8. Как мне в таком случае определить, что запись файла завершена и я могу отправлять ответ браузеру?

Comment: https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/file-system/how-to-read-files-in-nodejs и отдать результат в коллбек сервера, например.